# force html table in a new line (with only one <tr>)

Tags: html, css

I want to make the `td` wrap around to a new line dynamically, with using only a single `tr`. As you can see in the screenshot below, all of the `td` elements continue horizontally outside of the window. I want them to wrap underneath, inside of the window.

An example can be seen here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8c6ugyj/)

[image: draw]

```css
.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.gaba1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.gaba2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='hidden'>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">01 - D</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">02 - C</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">03 - E</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">04 - E</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">05 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">06 - D</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">07 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">08 - B</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">09 - D</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">10 - C</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">11 - B</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">12 - E</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">13 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">14 - D</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">15 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">16 - C</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">17 - B</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">18 - E</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">19 - B</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">20 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">01 - C</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">02 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">21 - D</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">22 - D</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">23 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">01 - B</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">01 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">01 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">01 - B</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">02 - C</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">03 - B</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you make a drawing?

Comment: Why is that a table in the first place?

Comment: I used the table so i could have the cells side by side .. giving me a responsive effect!! With only the div I could not .. or it gave me more work ...

Comment: @FábioZangirolami here the table doesn't make sense. Change instead of divs. To make responsive you must to make layout with percentage values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you WANT to use tables, you can achieve the desired look, including the background colors, by getting rid of the `div` elements and applying the following styles to the table columns:

```css
.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

/* every ODD td will have a gray background */
td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

/* every EVEN td will have a white background */
td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='hidden'>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>01 - D</td>
        <td>02 - C</td>
        <td>03 - E</td>
        <td>04 - E</td>
        <td>05 - A</td>
        <td>06 - D</td>
        <td>07 - A</td>
        <td>08 - B</td>
        <td>09 - D</td>
        <td>10 - C</td>
        <td>11 - B</td>
        <td>12 - E</td>
        <td>13 - A</td>
        <td>14 - D</td>
        <td>15 - A</td>
        <td>16 - C</td>
        <td>17 - B</td>
        <td>18 - E</td>
        <td>19 - B</td>
        <td>20 - A</td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">01 - C</td>
        <td>02 - A</td>
        <td>21 - D</td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">22 - D</td>
        <td>23 - A</td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">01 - B</td>
        <td>01 - A</td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">01 - A</td>
        <td>01 - B</td>
        <td>02 - C</td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">03 - B</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  </div>
```

However, the same can be accomplished using only `div` tags, which I would recommend doing instead of using a table.

Comment: all solutions were welcome .. however I will test and decide which one to use .. taking advantage, as I leave the alignment 'vertical-align: middle "? I could not make it...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the display value of `td` to `display: inline-block`. The default is `table-cell` which does not allow it to wrap to a new line and behaves like a single row.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/y8c6ugyj/3/)

```css
.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.gaba1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.gaba2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Added Code */

.hidden td {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='hidden'>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">01 - D</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">02 - C</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">03 - E</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">04 - E</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">05 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">06 - D</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">07 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">08 - B</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">09 - D</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">10 - C</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">11 - B</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">12 - E</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">13 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">14 - D</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">15 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">16 - C</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">17 - B</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">18 - E</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">19 - B</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">20 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">01 - C</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">02 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">21 - D</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">22 - D</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">23 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">01 - B</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">01 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">01 - A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">01 - B</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba2">02 - C</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="gaba1">03 - B</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: all solutions were welcome .. however I will test and decide which one to use .. taking advantage, as I leave the alignment 'vertical-align: middle "? I could not make it...

Answer (score 0):

Wes's response is great if you want a table.  However wrapping tables is not good responsive solution.  Instead you should use inline-block divs.

```
<div class="gaba1">01 - D</div>
<div class="gaba2">02 - C</div>
<div class="gaba1">03 - E</div>
...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y8c6ugyj/1/

Comment: You can do it with a table row.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after my post and made an edit.  My point is more that you shouldn't.